# Javascript stop time when certain condition is true?

Tags: javascript

Here is the JavaScript countdown code for Quiz:

```
var isClicked;
    isClicked = false;
    document.getElementById('quiz_button').onclick = function() {
    isClicked = true;
};

function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    const interval = setInterval(function() {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        if (timer !== 0) {
            --timer;
            <?php
            // start the time session...
            Session::set('startTime', time());
            ?>
        } else if (timer == 0) {
            if( isClicked == false ) {
                $( "#quiz_button" ).trigger( "click", function () {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                });
            } else {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var seconds = 10,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
        startTimer(seconds, display);
};
```

when the page is load then countdown started.

There is a `quiz_button` to complete the quiz. When it's clicked I set it `true` using JS. Otherwise, it triggers the button continuously.

But when the quiz is completed by pressing the button then countdown is still counting. I need to stop it. How can I stop it?

I did:

```
} else {
    clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Comment: i have demo for start stop and reset shall i put in ans ? or you need it in above same code

Comment: @DarshanDave Above code is better according to my logic :)